# Unexpected identifier with Ajax form submission reset

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

Having trouble understanding how to implement a form reset after a Ajax submission.  I tried calling `this.reset();` after the `success` function but I still get:

`form-submit.js:11 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

It works, but what am I missing/not doing correctly that keeps giving me this error?

(*If this is a repost please direct me to the correct question, I have yet to find a answer to resolve my issue after a few days. Thank you.*)

```
$( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
   event.preventDefault();
   console.log( $( this ).serialize() );
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'https://mysite.somewebaddress.com',
      data: $( this ).serialize(),
      success: function() {
          alert('Mail Sent');
      }
   });
   $( "form" )[0].reset();
   //this.reset();
});
```

Comment: I think it should be `$(this).reset();`

Comment: unfortunately the error still occurred

Comment: `console.log( $( this ).serialize() );` is working ?

Comment: yes, there's a log of all the data, but the reset makes it refresh the page

Comment: do you have any other forms in your page ?

Comment: separately, it's a static HTML project that goes out to a rails API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the success callback, `this` will refer to the Ajax request itself.
Additionally, if you try to reset the form after (outside) the Ajax block, the form would reset almost as soon as you submit.

Instead, try creating a variable with a different name and add the `complete` callback (which fires after the Ajax request has finished, regardless of success/fail.

Maybe something like:

```
$("form").on("submit", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log( $( this ).serialize() );
  var my_form = this;
  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: 'https://mysite.somewebaddress.com',
     data: $( this ).serialize(),
     success: function() {
         alert('Mail Sent');
         // my_form.reset() // or reset on success?
     },
     complete: function() {
        my_form.reset() // reset after submit
     }
  });
});
```

Comment: yes! thank you, I was wondering if calling it by something different in a `var` would break it, but you showed me something new!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#form').reset();
```

use after response